# What are the transaction return object attributes "c," "e," and "s" in an integer / uint return type?

Tags: solidity, transactions, truffle

I have a counter in a Solidity contract:

```
uint8 public transactionCounter;
function ContractConstructor() public {
    transactionCounter = 0;
}

function getTransactionCounter() returns (uint8) {
    return transactionCounter;
}

function trns() {
    transactionCounter += 1;
}
```

When interacting with the contract, i get back the `transactionCounter`

```
App.contract.XYContract.deployed()then(function(instance){
    return instance.getTransactionCounter.call();
}).then(function(counter) {
    console.log(counter);
});
```

In the JavaScript console, I get:

```
e {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(1)}
```

What are `s`, `e` and `c` and where is it documented?

Answer (score 2):

If the return value of a call is a number, you'll get back a [`BigNumber`](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/). You can use `counter.toString()` or `counter.toNumber()` (though note that the latter may lose precision on large numbers, which is why `BigNumber` exists in the first place).

Read more in [the web3.js documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js).

Comment: Or is it a transaction `result`: http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#processing-transaction-results

Comment: You didn't make a transaction, so no, it's not a transaction result. (You could easily verify what I told you by calling `.toString()` on it.)

Comment: I did `.toString()` it, it gave me `[Object object]` on the console.

Comment: I suppose it's possible Truffle is doing something weird? `web3.js` itself returns `BigNumber` objects when the return value is numeric, and what you pasted certainly looks like one.

Comment: I just noticed that the code you pasted isn't syntactically correct. Maybe share the actual code you're using (including the `.toString`)?

Comment: Ok... which part? Its a copy but i‘ll check again